My lights stop working when I use the hair particle system to make grass
(I'm quite new to blender) This happened in 3 separate blend files. At first, I was playing around with the particle system, and when I went into the rendered viewport I realized my light wasn't affecting the objects, I thought I might have pressed something unknowingly. I hadn't done much so I decided to start over from scratch in a new file. This time I turned on the rendered viewport from the start and as I was working, specifically; changing color via the color ramp node, suddenly the monkey in my scene stopped receiving light again. This time for sure I knew I didn't press any buttons I didn't know. After tinkering for a bit I found turning off scene world in the viewport shading tab brings back color to the monkey. I don't know much about world settings but after following a video on adding a sky it looked like the monkey was receiving light from the sky texture node. But I wanted to control the light with area lights so I decided to just start all over again and this time I didn't touch the world settings at all. I did almost everything the same as last time, this time the light didn't suddenly disappear on the color ramp node so I kept going but once again it just suddenly disappeared while I was changing the scale of the noise texture... what is going on? how do I fix this?
*I didn't touch the world setting in the last one
*I tried changing the light distance from the monkey and the light intensity


